# I am not able to make my navbar as sticky top in my portfolio website. What can I do to correct it?

Tags: html, css, navbar, sticky, portfolio

the link to my GitHub is given below:

<github.com/RapChikDude/portfolio>

I have tried to make it fixed also sticky by using bootstrap but it is not helping.

Comment: Post a [mcve] with code for your problem here - do not expect people to clone a repo to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used "sticky-top," but if your problem's right
to fix your Navbar to the top of the screen you can use "fixed-top". Or change your css to "position: fixed".

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
```